# How to move Output or Terminal back into the panel in the window layout?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently in VS Code, somewhere around v1.42 or v1.43, we gained the ability to move around the following windows/panels that used to be stuck in the panel:

1. Terminal
2. Output
3. Debug Console
4. Problems

They could be split into multiple items in the panel itself (side-by-side or top/bottom, depending on whether the panel was at the bottom or left/right), and even dragged into the side-bar.

This was great, but after moving all of these windows to the side-bar while experimenting, I can't find any way to move them back into the panel. The panel is now empty, except for 3 dots (an ellipsis) in the upper left corner. You can still hide/show the panel, and move it left, bottom, or right, but there is nothing in it, and you can't drag anything to it. Dragging the terminal into the panel shows an icon that looks like it will successfully move (it's not the icon with the circle/cross-out you get other places it won't drop), but when releasing the click-drag, nothing happens.

---

I had just upgraded to v1.45.0 when this happened. It appears to be a defect, unless I'm missing something. Does anyone have a way to put the terminal or one of these other windows back in the panel, or reset their position? I combed the settings, and tried to find default setting's files (system or user) that might hold info on what is in the panel vs. the sidebar, etc., but couldn't find anything via search or on my PC. Any ideas?

---

***Note: This is NOT about moving the panel between the left/right/bottom positions, or selecting the terminal/output/etc. in the panel itself. That's "old news", this is a recent feature.***

Here is a view with the Terminal, Output, Debug Console, and Problems put at the top of the sidebar toolbar, and Terminal focused. The Panel is just to the right of the sidebar window, set to the "left" position, completely blank and useless. The "welcome" window on the far right side:

[image]

And here are my current settings:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96117 (Empty panel behaves weird)

Suggested fix:

Run the command `View: Reset View Locations` in the command palette.

Comment: Perfect - that was the command I needed. Thanks!  I guess the rule for the moment is not to move all the tabs out of the panel..

Answer (score 2):

The issue reported by @Mark is now fixed and the problem easily solved using the `view: move secondary side bar views to panel`.